# Is it possible to create GUI that looks like Mac in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt-quick, qt4.8

I want to make my project look as  Mac themed. Is there any library to make it Mac styled.
PS: i don't own a Mac, so i cant use Macstyle n other Mac based libraries.
Kindly help in making my app have a Mac feel.

Comment: I believe there is "QML" in Qt4+ that allows you to adjust L&F with www-esque styles, though I'm not incredibly familiar with it...  may want to start there, someone may have already done this work.

Comment: Qt Widgets should replicate system look and feel on Mac OS by default. However I can't confirm how effective it is because I don't own a Mac myself.

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to achieve exactly.  But in general yes, you can apply styles in QML to give the built-in components a Mac-like look and feel.

Comment: Is this a question for Qt 4.8 specifically? If not, please remove the 4.8 tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to implement it yourself. You'll need to implement your own `QStyle` that looks and acts like the mac style without running on a Mac. This would be best done on a Mac, porting the existing style to use progressively less and less support from the native styling. Otherwise it'd be a huge undertaking - just look at [how big the Mac style is](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/styles/qmacstyle_mac.mm) - ~7k lines, and it still uses Apple's APIs to draw all the elements!

The biggest problem I see is that you cannot reuse Apple's visuals and designs. You need to consult a lawyer to figure out how close to OS X look you can get.